# Remove duplicate element pairs from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, coordinates

I have an array that looks like this:

```
1.  coordinates = [ [16.343345, 35.123523],
2.                  [14.325423, 34.632723],
3.                  [15.231512, 35.426914],
4.                  [16.343345, 35.123523],
5.                  [15.231512, 32.426914] ]
```

The latitude on line 5 is the same as on line 3, but they have different longitudes and are therefore not duplicates.

Both the latitude and longitude are the same on line 3 and 6, and are therefore duplicates and one should be removed.

Comment: You should update your question to include any attempts you've made already.

Comment: Have you tried sorting them and then looping over the result comparing the current record to the next?

Comment: `15,231512, 35,426914` (4 integers) shouldn't it be `15.231512, 35.426914` (2 floats)?

Comment: For tasks like removing duplicates from lists, your best bet is often to use one of the pre-existing JS libraries like [lodash](http://lodash.com/), since this code has a lot more road-testing in it than any code you might write.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, also? Line 6 doesn't exist and, by my reckoning, lines 1 and 4 & lines 3 and 5 match

Answer (score 13):

The difficulty in this question that different arrays never compare equal even if they contain same values. Therefore direct comparison methods, like `indexOf` won't work.

The following pattern might be useful to solve this. Write a function (or use a built-in one) that converts arrays to scalar values and checks if these values are unique in a set.

```
uniq = function(items, key) {
    var set = {};
    return items.filter(function(item) {
        var k = key ? key.apply(item) : item;
        return k in set ? false : set[k] = true;
    })
}
```

where `key` is a "hash" function that convert `items` (whatever they are) to comparable scalar values. In your particular example, it seems to be enough just to apply `Array.join` to arrays:

```
uniqueCoords = uniq(coordinates, [].join)
```

Comment: Be aware that [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is not available in IE < 9

Answer (score 5):

You can use standard javascript function [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    for(var j = i + 1; j < coordinates.length; ) {
        if(coordinates[i][0] == coordinates[j][0] && coordinates[i][1] == coordinates[j][1])
            // Found the same. Remove it.
            coordinates.splice(j, 1);
        else
            // No match. Go ahead.
            j++;
    }    
}
```

However, if you have thousands of points it will work slowly, than you need to consider to sort values at first, then remove duplicates in one loop.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the answer from [thg435](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/thg435) (It does not allow me to post comments) and prototype it also using jQuery instead, so this will work on all browsers using it (Even IE7)

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function (key) {
    var set = {};
    return $.grep(this, function (item) {
        var k = key
            ? key.apply(item)
            : item;
        return k in set
            ? false
            : set[k] = true;
    });
}
```

You can use it like:

```
arr = arr.uniq([].join);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not on Safari this single liner could do the job

```js
var arr = [[16.343345, 35.123523],
           [14.325423, 34.632723],
           [15.231512, 35.426914],
           [16.343345, 35.123523],
           [15.231512, 32.426914]],
    lut = {},
    red = arr.filter(a => lut[a] ? false : lut[a] = true);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(red,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to create another array keeping only unique coordinate pairs

```
var uniqueCoors = [];
var doneCoors = [];
for(var x = 0; x < coordinates.length; x++) {
    var coorStr = coordinates[x].toString();

    if(doneCoors.indexOf(coorStr) != -1) {
        // coordinate already exist, ignore
        continue;
    }

    doneCoors.push(coorStr);
    uniqueCoors.push(coordinates[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortCoordinates(arr){
    var obj = {};
    for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++){
        var el = arr[i];
        var lat = el[0];
        var lng = el[1];

        if(!obj[lat + lng]){
            obj[lat + lng] = [lat, lng];
        } 
    }

    var out = [];
    for(p in obj){
        out.push([obj[p][0], obj[p][1]]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about coordinates[][] dataType. Make the comparison accordingly.

```
  var dubJRows= new Array();
  for(int i = 0; i <  coordinates.length -2; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j <  coordinates.length -1; j++){
        if (i != j && chk_dubJRows_not_contains(j)) {
           innerArray1 [1][1] = coordinates[i];
           innerArray2 [1][1] = coordinates[j];
           if ( innerArray1 [1][0] == innerArray2[1][0] 
                   && innerArray1[1][1] == innerArray2[1][1]) {
               dubJRows.push(j);
            }
         }
       }
    }
    //REMOVE ALL dubJRows from coordinates.
```

Comment: This is O(n^2) and won't scale well at all. Also, there's no point scanning `j` from 0 to `coordinates.length` as you'll be duplicating some of your comparisons. For instance, `i=3,j=2` is the same comparison as `i=2,j=3`.

Comment: OP is using JavaScript, not Java